# Matplotlib linestyle inconsistent dashes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting just a simple scatterplot with MPL 1.4.0.  I want to control the number of dashes on the figures I am plotting because currently even though I set a linestyle, the dashes are too close to each other so it doesn't look like a properly dashed line.

```
#load cdeax,cdeay,gsix,gsiy,reich all are arrays of shape (380,)
figfit = plt.figure(); axfit = figfit.gca() 

axfit.plot(cdeax,np.log(cdeay),'ko', alpha=.5); axfit.plot(gsix,np.log(gsiy), 'kx')
axfit.plot(cdeax,cdeafit,'k-'); axfit.plot(gsix,gsifit,'k:')
longevityregplot[1].plot(gsix,np.log(reich_l),'k-.')
```

[image: Why I want to control dashes]

---

```
#load cdeax,cdeay,gsix,gsiy,reich all are arrays of shape (380,)
figfit = plt.figure(); axfit = figfit.gca() 

axfit.plot(cdeax,np.log(cdeay),'ko', alpha=.5); axfit.plot(gsix,np.log(gsiy), 'kx')
axfit.plot(cdeax,cdeafit,'k-',dashes = [10,10]); axfit.plot(gsix,gsifit,'k:',dashes=[10,10])
longevityregplot[1].plot(gsix,np.log(reich_l),'k-.')
```

[image: What I end up the 1st time]

However the above is what I get. Rather than a uniformly-dashed line, the lines get dashed at the ends to varying degrees but no matter what values I use for dashes, the dashing is never uniform.

I'm afraid I really don't know what the problem is here... Any ideas?

I have pasted the arrays I am using here: http://pastebin.com/rJ5Jjfmm
You should be able to just copy/paste them to your IDE for the above code to run.

Cheers!

EDIT:

Just with the single line plotted:

```
axfit.plot(cdeax,cdeafit,'k-',dashes = [10,10]);
```

[image]

EDIT2: pastebin link changed to include all data

EDIT3: Histogram of point density along the x axis:

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you're plotting two dashed lines on top of each other and they're cancelling out each others' dashes.   If you do just `axfit.plot(cdeax,cdeafit,'k-',dashes = [10,10])` in a cleared axis, how's the line?

Comment: I've edited my post with a new image, the same thing happens.

Comment: Check the data for repeated or out-of-order data in the 5-10 deg range?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the paste with cdeafit and gsifit included. 

There isn't any data repeating as these are individual gridpoints that I've pulled out from a grid. There are an uneven amount of points along the x axis, as shown in the histogram I've included, but the largest amount isn't in  the 5-10 deg range.

Comment: They don't have to repeat, but if -- and this seems unlikely, except that it *looks* right -- if the plotting backtracks, you can get this effect. Like the x-values run [1,2,5,3,4] instead of [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: so you're fitting a first-order polynomial (linear)?

Comment: It is a 1st-order polynomial, yes, the data on Y has been log-transformed. I  edited the code to reflect this as the pastebin link has non-logged Y data.

Comment: What das `axfit.plot(sorted(cdeax),sorted(cdeafit),'k-',dashes = [10,10]);` gives? (should be allowed as long as your fit curve is monotonically increasing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what @cphlewis said is correct, you may have some x-axis backtracking.  If I sort everything it looks ok to me (did my own fitting since I still don't see the fits on pastebin)

```
# import your data here
import math
figfit = plt.figure(); axfit = figfit.gca() 

cdea = zip(cdeax,cdeay)
cdea = np.array(sorted(cdea, key = lambda x: x[0]))

gsi = zip(gsix,gsiy)
gsi = np.array(sorted(gsi, key = lambda x: x[0]))

cdeafit2 = np.polyfit(cdea[:,0],cdea[:,1],1)
gsifit2 = np.polyfit([x[0] for x in gsi],[math.log(x[1]) for x in gsi],1)

cdeafit = [x*cdeafit2[0] + cdeafit2[1] for x in cdea[:,0]]

gsifit = [math.exp(y) for y in [x*gsifit2[0] + gsifit2[1] for x in gsi[:,0]]]

axfit.plot(cdea[:,0],cdea[:,1],'ko', alpha=.5); axfit.plot(gsi[:,0],gsi[:,1], 'kx')
axfit.plot(cdea[:,0],cdeafit,'k-',dashes = [10,10]); axfit.plot(gsi[:,0],gsifit,'k:',dashes=[10,10])
#longevityregplot[1].plot(gsix,np.log(reich_l),'k-.') # not sure what this is
axfit.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

[image: fits only]